# React with Typescript Array of promises

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, promise, polkadot-js

I have the following function:

```
function querryProposals(hash:string) {

      let t = api?.query.backgroundCouncil.proposalOf(
        
        hash,(data1:any)=>{
        let data0 = data1.toPrimitive().args.account as InjectedAccountWithMeta;    
        let data = proposals;
        if (data0 && !data.includes(data0)){
          data.push(data0);                    
          dispatch1({type:`SET_PROPOSALS`,payload:data}); 
          //console.log(data)
          return data
        }        
      }
      );
      
      return t
    }
```

The commented `console.log(data)` will return the expected list of data, however, `console.log(t)` is always just return:`[Promise,Promise,Promise,...]`

below is the portion where I actually use the function and check the returned value as `newl`:

```
 api.query.backgroundCouncil.proposals((hash: string[]) => {
      if (hash.length > 0) {
        let newl=hash.map((x)=>querryProposals(x)?.then(list=>list));  
       console.log(newl);       
        
      }
    });
```

I really don't know what to do, I am expecting the returned variable `t` to be the same as the returned variable `data`

thanks in advance

Kazu

Comment: What is `api?.query.backgroundCouncil`? What are its methods doing? Are they part of a framework you use?

Comment: short answer is yes, I am using the polkadot-js api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). This function lets you turn an array of promises into an array of the promises' results.

```
const someArrayOfPromises = [promise, otherPromise, otherPromise2];
const arrayOfPromiseResults = await Promise.all(someArrayOfPromises);
```

alternatively:

```
const someArrayOfPromises = [promise, otherPromise, otherPromise2];
Promise.all(someArrayOfPromises).then((arrayOfPromiseResults) => {
  handleResults(arrayOfPromiseResults);
});
```